# $\sum\frac{k^k}{3^{k^2}}$ series be convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Would the following series be convergent or divergent.

$\sum\frac{k^k}{3^{k^2}}$

I applied the root test to the following series and got.

$(\frac{k^k}{3^{k^2}})^{1/k}$

I got $\lim$ $k\rightarrow\infty$

$\frac{k}{3^k}$

using Le Hospitals rule I got

$\frac{1}{3^k}$

which is zero

0<1 convergent?

Comment: Except for a constant in the denominator after applying l'Hopital's rule (which doesn't change the limit), it looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct limit and correct conclusion; you simply have a slight error in the derivative of the denominator, $(3^k)' = (\log 3)3^k$.

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense